# Sum array integer values and Combine duplicated non integer values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array as shown below, I want to get their non integer duplicated values as one value associated to index key and plus the integer values in their next indexes, in a new index. The one are not duplicated just sort them in same array.

**Data Array I have**

```
Array
 (
 [0] => class 1
 [1] => 10
 [2] => class 1
 [3] => 10
 [4] => class 2
 [5] => 30
 [6] => late fine
 [7] => 50
 [8] => late fine
 [9] => 100
 )
```

**The way I want**

```
Array
 (
 [0] => class 1
 [1] => 20
 [2] => class 2
 [3] => 30
 [4] => late fine
 [5] => 150
 )
```

**CODE**

```
$i=0; $x=0; $rec = array();

while($i < count($data)){       
    while($x < count($data)){           
        if($data[$i] == $data[$x]){         
            $rec[] = $data[$i];             
        }                   
        $x++;
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I don't know PHP, so I'll just try to explain my thinking. You can start with a for loop that starts at `i = 0` and increments `i=i+2`, while less than the array length, then an if statement that checks the value, and then lastly, when pulling the data out, you use `i+1` to index. Hope that makes sense

Comment: `I want to get their duplicated keys as one key in an index`.  There are no duplicated keys, only duplicated values.  I don't really get what you're asking, it seems like your expected output is just a deduplicated array with 20 instead of 10?

Comment: sorry my bad I just updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you would want to end up with an array of values, where every other value should represent the sum for the previous value.

If I were you, I would sort them as a KV array like so:

```
$summed_array = [];
$array = [
    'class 1',
    40,
    'class 1',
    10,
    'class 2',
    20,
    'test 1',
    20,
    'test 1',
    40
]; // Your array

for( $i = 0; $i<count($array); $i++ ){

    // Do the following procedure for every other instance
    if( $i % 2 == 0 ){
        $summed_array[$array[$i]] = array_key_exists( $array[$i], $summed_array ) ? ( $summed_array[$array[$i]] + $array[$i+1] ) : $array[$i+1];
    }

}
```

This would give you an output like follows:

```
Array ( [class 1] => 50 [class 2] => 20 [test 1] => 60 )
```

Comment: but I need the result in index order only

Comment: like " the way I want " above in my question

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Ole Haugset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51433021), but since you insist on the sequential result, here's a solution that does that:

```
$data = [
  'class 1',
  10,
  'class 1',
  10,
  'class 2',
  30,
  'late fine',
  50,
  'late fine',
  100
];

$temp = [];
foreach( array_chunk( $data, 2 ) as list( $key, $value ) ) {
  $temp[ $key ] = isset( $temp[ $key ] ) ? $temp[ $key ] + $value : $value;
}
// until here it was basically similar to Ole's solution

$result = [];
foreach( $temp as $key => $value ) {
  $result[] = $key;
  $result[] = $value;
}

var_dump( $result );
```

[<sup>view parsed online @ eval.in</sup>](https://eval.in/1039500)

Comment: Both answers are great, and I have respect for both, ethically I should accept Ole answer as he dive in first, and technically decent's answer as he provide same as I want, let's up vote for Decent :)   everyone happy

Comment: Nice use of the array_chunk as list there @Decent Dabbler. I learned something new today :)